# Printing prime numbers - console.log loop result to html

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator

My goal was to print out prime numbers (not including the number inputted) below the original value of the input. When I wrote the function, I am able to see the results I need with `console.log(i)` but when I change it to `return i`, I don't get the results when I call the function `showPrime(n)`. I think the issue is how I'm returning the results in showPrime(), would I need to create an empty string?

```js
function isPrime(n) {
  //2 is an exception
  if ((n <= 1) || n % 2 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  };
};

function showPrime(n) {
  let numbies = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i) === true) {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}

//user interface logic
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    n = $("input#numberInput").val();
    alert(showPrime(n));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Prime Number Sifter</h1>
  <p>When you input a number, the program will return all prime numbers below it (not including the number). <em>Note: While 2 is a prime number, the program won't return anything since 1 is not!</em></p>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="numberInput">Input </label>
      <input type="integer" class="form-control" id="numberInput" placeholder="Enter number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="output">
    <p><span class="show"></span></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `return` it will stop the function execution, so you will stop just after the first number (pratically only 0).

You should take an array of numbers and return it

```js
function isPrime(n) {
  //2 is an exception
  if ((n <= 1) || n % 2 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  };
};

function showPrime(n) {
  let numbies = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i) === true) {
      // console.log(i)
      numbies.push(i)
    }
  }  
  return numbies;
}


//user interface logic
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    n = $("input#numberInput").val();
    alert(showPrime(n));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Prime Number Sifter</h1>
  <p>When you input a number, the program will return all prime numbers below it (not including the number). <em>Note: While 2 is a prime number, the program won't return anything since 1 is not!</em></p>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="numberInput">Input </label>
      <input type="integer" class="form-control" id="numberInput" placeholder="Enter number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="output">
    <p><span class="show"></span></p>
  </div>
```

If you want just the highest prime number, make the inverse for loop.

```js
function showPrime(n) {
  let numbies = []
  for (let i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (isPrime(i) === true) {
      // console.log(i)
      return i;
    }
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a return statement interrupts and ends the function. if you put `return i` into the for loop (if I understood correctly) the function ends and returns 0.